# How to calculate TF-IDF in OracleSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, tf-idf

This is a text mining project. The purpose of this project is to see how every word weighs differently in a different document.

Now I am having two tables, one table with TF information (WORD | WordFrequency_in_EachFile), another table with IDF (WORD | HowManyFile_have_EachWord). I am not sure what query use for this calculation.

The math I am trying to do here is:
`WordFrequency_in_EachFile*(log(N/HowManyFile_have_EachWord)+1)`
N is the total number of document. 
Below is my code:

```
create table TF_IDF (WORD, TF*IDF) as
select A.frequency*((log(10,132366/B.totalcount)+1)) 
from term_frequency A, document_frequency B
where A.WORD=B.WORD;
```

Here 1323266 is the total number of my documents, and totalcount is how many documents a word shows.

Since I am new to SQL, I would appreciate a little explanation to your code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what the link is, you want that calculation for each word, and that's common to both tables? Where does N come from as you don't seem to be able to imfer it from either table? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: This data is from multiple documents. I counted how many times a word shows in one document (TF), and how many documents a word shows. Now I want to calculate TF-IDF: `how many times a term shows in one table`*`log(total number of document/ how many document a word show)+1`. I have just updated my query. Not sure if it is right. Also, I can not seem to create a new table to store this result. Do you know why is that? Thanks.

Comment: I know I am not supposed to chat here. But thank you for answering so many of my questions. Also, I just figured that you are at U.K!!

Answer (score 0):

Calculation looks good, but there are some invalid syntax.

Right variant may look like below:

```
create table TF_IDF as
select 
  A.Word                                           as Word,
  A.frequency*( log(10, 132366/B.totalcount) + 1)  as TFIDF
from 
  term_frequency     A, 
  document_frequency B
where 
  A.WORD=B.WORD
;
```

In `CREATE ... AS SELECT ...` statement you don't need column specifications. Column names and types derived from field aliases. 
Also, you must provide values for `Word` column in new table.
And one more point: there are one excess pair of brackets in expression.